# Enabling R package to access data on the server from local machine

Tags: r, server, r-package

I have written an R package with a function that use the data from the server.

```
Masterdata::alarmMasterdata
function (alarm_id = NULL, alarm_name = NULL) 
{
    df <- readRDS("/srv/shiny-server/Masterdata/Alarminfo.RDS")
    if (!is.null(alarm_id)) {
        df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(TDIId %in% alarm_id)
    }
    if (!is.null(alarm_name)) {
        df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(AlarmName %in% alarm_name)
    }
    df
}
```

`Alarminfo.RDS` is a data which will update every day via a cron job on the server.

As long as I'm working on Rstudio on the server, everything is fine.
But when I install the package on my local machine, how should I modify the `alarmMasterdata` function to be able to access the data ?!

Comment: SSH or SCP? Static web server? `plumber` API endpoint?

Comment: What method of user-authentication are you expecting? Is there a shared filesystem (e.g., NFS, CIFS)?

Comment: @r2evans I'm connecting to the server via ssh key from my windows machine. But how I should do the authentication inside my R package for local users ?

Comment: Do all of your local users have SSH keys?

Comment: @r2evans Not necessarily

Comment: I suggest that this discussion should have nothing to do with R, it should be agnostic to the language, instead focusing on *"how do I securely deploy a `file` to the public?"* Assuming that you are making it available to anybody, I'd put it as a well-known endpoint on a webserver, e.g., `https://my.server.com/data/masterData/Alarminfo.rds`. You could use `ssh` to get it there, but from there it is merely a `download.file(.)` call away for R users.

Comment: That arbitrary endpoint (in my opinion) should likely be specific, nested away from the rest of your web presence, and possibly protected against SEO and webcrawlers (i.e., `robots.txt` or similar).